# Sharing Eclipse using NFS - Issue?

Tags: linux, centos, eclipse

I am sharing Eclipse with another gentlemen over a Network File System. Strangely, when he started using it, the `make` tool did not properly work. I suspect this is because the server cannot handle the both users using Eclipse at the same time. Is there a fix/workaround?

Comment: Sounds like you are not using source control. You should each have your own local copy of the source code.

Comment: Are you sharing the source code or the Eclipse program? What *exactly* do you mean by "did not properly work"? Was there any error message? Did it summon Cthulhu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the same files at the same time on the same file system, that's sure a good situation to get all kinds of problems. Can't you afford each your own copy of Eclipse?

Comment: No ;),  I guess I could. But how come this problem happen? The error I am getting is that when ever I do a build I don't see the change, even if I comment out a whole section !!!!!!

Comment: You probably should, but I'm not sure Eclipse is part of the problem here. You can start many instances of Eclipse without big problem. I'm thinking that you might be using an esoteric setup. Are you sharing the source code on NFS too? Are you sharing the build tools on NFS? Sharing Eclipse might work, but if you say yes to any of these, rethink your setup. Also, you might like to check this thread http://superuser.com/a/33543/25004 In particular take a look at how NFS manages his locks (or doesn't)...